# mariadb not responding after many request

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb

i developing a site with laravel 5.2 and now it's ready to launch.
but i have a problem.
i used loadimpact.com to run a stress test before launch.
loadimpact sends 50 virtual users in one minute to my site. but after a few seconds site doesn't respond.
laravel show me this error:

```
ErrorException in Connector.php line 55: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111) (View: /var/www/...
```

and when i restart server every thing works fine.
i think when visitors go up, mariadb goes down.
i have also increase max_connection variable (it stuck at 214) but it steal goes down.
what can i do?
thanks.

Comment: not a very helpful error, try monitor CPU, memory, threads as you tress test it. Also what kind of hosing is this one?

Comment: Look at your database error log. Something's severely wrong if it keeps crashing.

Comment: `max_connections` is a constant.  What about `Max_used_connections`?